# Floating Point Addition Behavior - CPP

Tags: c++, graphics, floating-point

I have a question regarding floating point addition- I understand errors are easy to come by, but this one has me stumped.
In my code, I compute 3 values that are floating point- z1, z2, and z3. They are interpolated z values for z-buffering.

To get the final z coordinate, I have float z = z1 + z2 + z3.
When I print z, I realized it is always coming out to the same number- which is resulting in substantial z-fighting in the images generated by my program.

```
                    float z1 = (bry[0] * (1.0 / v1.m_pos[2]));
                    float z2 = (bry[1] * (1.0 / v2.m_pos[2]));
                    float z3 = (bry[2] * (1.0 / v3.m_pos[2]));

                    cout << "z1 is " << z1 << endl;
                    cout << "z2 is " << z2 << endl;
                    cout << "z3 is " << z3 << endl;

                    float z = z1 + z2 + z3;
                    cout << " z computed to  be " << z << cout;
```

For context, here are resulting print statements.

```
z1 is 0.59306
z2 is 0.156332
z3 is 0.250608
z computed to  be 10xa45504

z1 is 0.700896
z2 is 0.0484997
z3 is 0.250605
z computed to  be 10xa45504
```

I'm not exactly sure why the printing of the z value is the way it is, or what I may be doing incorrectly to add these values together. Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The code you posted shouldn't show that output so without knowing the real code it's hard to say.

Comment: Why would you expect the `z`values to be different?

Comment: What is the `<< cout` part supposed to be doing?

Comment: This is obviously not your exact, real code. Please don't do that. Post a [MCVE] so people can copy the code and try it out. Copy and paste your real code (of the MCVE) into the browser.

Comment: You should have questioned the fact that the output contains an `x`, which is not possible for a floating-point literal. And knowing that the value of `z` is `1`, you have the extra characters `0xa45504`, a 32 bits hexadecimal constant. Going back to the `cout` statement, what follows `<< z` gives you the explanation.

Answer (score 8):

That last line is printing two things:  The value of `z` (1), and the address of the `cout` object (0xa45504).  Perhaps you meant `endl` instead?

Comment: Doesn't even compile in VC++: "Error C2678 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"